# Grab POST data from a dynamically created element with php

Tags: php, forms

I have a form element which looks like a button (a simple div) with values like `350`x`300`, `450`x`600`... and you can dynamically add more of these buttons with javascript. My question is how to grab data of those buttons with plain PHP after form submit?

If I change those divs to element `<input type="text">` when it is not a button anymore. Is it possible to style such input fields to look completely different?

Also tried adding `name` attributes to simple divs or changing to `input type="button"` elements, but PHP seems not to grab these values and it only grabs from `<input type="text" >` am I right?

Comment: How are you calling your php script? So you have an actual form with a submit button on it, just no true "inputs"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of styling your inputs, consider modifying the JavaScript which creates these "buttons" to also append, or modify, a **hidden input** which contains your desired value:

```
<input type="hidden" name="size" value="800x600">
```

And you can add such inputs to your form as necessary, which will submit it as POST data as expected.

You might need some clever JS to add, modify, or remove these hidden inputs based on your user's interactions.

*Note that you can style inputs, but it may be more trouble than it's worth.*

Comment: OMG, this is what I needed. Genius!

Comment: Great, if this fully answers your question, consider accepting it. Otherwise, let me know what's missing and I'll try to extend it :)

Answer (score 0):

div containers are not form elements. I suggest you look into how to properly [process forms with PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php).

div containers are just not submitted by the client when a form is submitted. Therefore, PHP has no chance to get to this data ever.

edit: sorry, and yes: you can style the button any way you want using CSS. The [button element](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/button) may be the thing you are looking for. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can style an input field to look almost anyway you want. Check out these tutorials on how to do so, cross browser.

http://www.onextrapixel.com/2012/10/26/custom-style-all-your-form-elements-with-pure-css-and-no-javascript/

https://css-tricks.com/styling-cross-browser-compatible-range-inputs-css/

That way you'll be able to use the name attribute which will send your data in the headers.